# Facebook app help on basics and access token PHP SDK for a beginner

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

I would like to know how can I get an access token easily for my Facebook app? I'm new to this so a step by step explanation would be appreciated. I intend on making an app which displays user's data such as name, bio, dob and email. Moreover the app also shows the feed from a page. Using the page's id/name or category. So far I have this. Somethings might be extra here as I was trying to experiment.

```php
//Loading the SDK
require_once("facebook.php");

//Setting up APP parameters
$config = array();
$config['appId'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
$config['secret'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
// Getting the user id
$user = $facebook->getUser();
$user_me = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {

$params = array(
  'scope' => 'read_stream, user_about_me',
  'redirect_uri' => 'http://fblabs.chimpitup.com/'
);
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the PHP SDK then you don't need to know the access token explicitly. You also don't need to get or set it using `getAccessToken` and `setAccessToken`. All of this is handled by the user clicking on the link generated from `$facebook->getLoginUrl($params);` and then the function `getUser`.

So remove

```php
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
```

Also the following line will trigger an error since it's not in a try-catch and it's redundant with the next few lines.

```php
$user_me = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
```

After knowing you have authenticated with this

```php
if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
```

You can then make a call with a conditional

```php
if ($user) {
    $page_posts = $facebook->api('/PAGE_ID/posts');
}
```

Where `PAGE_ID` is the id of the page you are looking to get the feed from

`$page_posts` is a collection of post objects that can be accessed by looping through

```php
foreach($page_posts['data'] as $post){
  $post_link = $post['actions'][0]['link'];
  $page_id = $post['from']['id'];
  $page_name = $post['from']['name'];
  $message = ($post['message']) ? $post['message'] : " ";
  $name = ($post['name']) ? $post['name'] : " ";
  $story = ($post['story']) ? $post['story'] : " ";
  $post_time = $post['updated_time'];
}
```

For example displaying it in HTML

```php
    <div id="stream">
<?php foreach($user_posts['data'] as $post){  
  $post_link = $post['actions'][0]['link'];
  $page_id = $post['from']['id'];
  $page_name = $post['from']['name'];
  $message = ($post['message']) ? $post['message'] : " ";
  $name = ($post['name']) ? $post['name'] : " ";
  $story = ($post['story']) ? $post['story'] : " ";
  $post_time = $post['updated_time'];
?>
      <div class="post">    
        <div class="picture">
          <a href="http://facebook.com/<?php echo $page_id; ?>"><img src="http://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $page_id; ?>/picture?type=square"/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="body">
          <a href="http://facebook.com/<?php echo $page_id; ?>" class="actor"><?php echo $page_name; ?></a>
          <span class="message"><?php echo $message; ?></span><br>
          <span class="message"><?php echo $name; ?></span><br>
          <span class="message"><?php echo $story; ?></span>
          <div class="meta">
            <a href="<?php echo $post_link ?>" class="permalink"><?php echo date("F j g:i a", strtotime($post_time)); ?></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
<?php } ?>
    </div><!-- end #stream -->
```

See https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=facebook%2Fposts for an example of how a page posts is made up and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/ to know how a post object is made

See the example https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php and PHP Getting Started Section https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/ and where some of the code in this answer was sourced https://github.com/phwd/hellopageposts/blob/master/index.php

Comment: Well I did try what you said even before but this is the error that I always get

**Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown in...**

Comment: @HamzaKazi I'm assuming the code you presented above is not the whole code and you did go through the authorization link generated by `$facebook->getLoginUrl($params);` ?

Comment: I've provided the entire php part of my index file but if it is really needed then I can update the html body part of it but I don't think that has anything to do with the permissions.

Comment: @HamzaKazi it matters so that it is understood you and the users are indeed clicking the link that comes from `$loginUrl` if you are then you would see some kind of response be it error or otherwise.

Comment: I think I failed to make myself clear. Actually I get the error mentioned above as soon as I open the index page. Without even doing or seeing anything but I've figured out the issue. I'm using the example.php as a base although it would be helpful if you could highlight that how can I get feed from a specific page using it's id after I've logged in with the Facebook on my app?

Comment: Wonderful. This was very easy to understand. Will try this in the morning and provide feedback. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey I tried the code above and it says Invalid arguments provided in for each. Can you explain why would I get that here? Plus I've seen the links you provided and turns out I do need the acccess token to do more things other than the basic so is this how I would get the access token? Got this from your github link

Comment: `$facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();
  $app_token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
                . "client_id=" . $facebook->getAppId()
                . "&client_secret=" . $facebook->getAppSecret()
                . "&grant_type=client_credentials";

  $response = file_get_contents($app_token_url);
  $app_access_token = null;
  parse_str($response, $app_access_token);

  $input_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();`

Comment: @HamzaKazi ignore that, it's not really what you want now. I've already stated that you get an access token by clicking a link or being redirected to a link that was generated from `getLoginUrl` http://dragon.ak.fbcdn.net/cfs-ak-ash4/84991/914/165799420225798-/server-side-diagram.png. Please make your base code work i.e. example.php before proceeding further https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php, it's very straightforward, nothing has to be changed.

Comment: Hey thankyou for your help @phwd turns out there was a silly little mistake in my php code which I probably made during copy pasting the code here. Furthermore I used one of your example apps from your GitHub which had something which extracted the Access Token so the apps working as it should now. Thumbs up to you!